# How to read multiple jsonArrays from a file?

Tags: java, android, json

I want to read many jsonArrays from a file.

these are the JsonArrays in the file:

```
 [{name:"John",preis:"123",bild:1235},
  {name:"Smith",preis:"256",bild:7205},
  {name:"Steeven",preis:"632",bild:324035}]

 [{name:"Hans",preis:"85",bild:1005},
  {name:"Peter",preis:"420",bild:22205},
  {name:"Joe",preis:"200",bild:3240}]

 [{name:"Jane",preis:"355",bild:10505},
  {name:"Calith",preis:"630",bild:96505},
  {name:"Eva",preis:"260",bild:32440}]
```

I can not read the whole file, but i can read only the first jsonArray from the file.

here is my code to read it:

```js
ArrayList<Werkzeug> myWerkzeuge = new ArrayList<Werkzeug>();
        String alteBestellung = "";

        try {

            FileInputStream fileInputStream = openFileInput(fileName);
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

            String line;

            while ( (line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){

                alteBestellung = alteBestellung + line;

            }

            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(alteBestellung);

            for (int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length(); ++i){

                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                String name_werkzeuge = (String) jsonObject.get("name");
                String preis_werkzeuge = (String) jsonObject.get("preis");
                Integer bild_werkzeuge = Integer.valueOf( (String)jsonObject.get("bild") );

                myWerkzeuge.add( new Werkzeug(name_werkzeuge, preis_werkzeuge, bild_werkzeuge));
            }

            fileInputStream.close();
            inputStreamReader.close();
            bufferedReader.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String bestellung = " ";

        for (int i = 0; i< myWerkzeuge.size(); ++i) {

            bestellung = bestellung + "\n" + myWerkzeuge.get(i).getName() + "   " + myWerkzeuge.get(i).getPreis() + " €" + myWerkzeuge.get(i).getBild();
        }

        bestellungsTextView.setText( bestellung );
```

How to read these three jsonArrays from this file?

Comment: use a loop for the JSONObject to get JSONArray like `JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray(index)`

Comment: Need to create valid JSON String before getting all JSONArray's f

Comment: your [JSONArray](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html) may stop at the first "]" when you do JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(alteBestellung); so try to split it in 3 and then create it or add "[ ]"

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a valid json.
You probably want a JsonArray of JsonArray :

```
[
 [{name:"John",preis:"123",bild:1235},
  {name:"Smith",preis:"256",bild:7205},
  {name:"Steeven",preis:"632",bild:324035}],

 [{name:"Hans",preis:"85",bild:1005},
  {name:"Peter",preis:"420",bild:22205},
  {name:"Joe",preis:"200",bild:3240}],

 [{name:"Jane",preis:"355",bild:10505},
  {name:"Calith",preis:"630",bild:96505},
  {name:"Eva",preis:"260",bild:32440}]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not valid json .
First of all make a valid json.

Comment: he said a file though!